# if i deleted by mistake my storyboard how can i bring it back?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I deleted my storyboard by mistake, i wanted to delete something in it but the whole file was deleted...can i bring it back??

I highlighted the vc in the storyboard that i wanted to delete, hit delete, and b oom the whole storyboard file was gone

is there a history feature..? please help

Comment: Don't you have backups? And version control? Xcode has built in support for git and offers to create a repository with every new project, but that only helps if you have been committing changes into git. Finder has support for automated backups via Time Machine but that only works if you've enabled it. If you aren't using either of those (you should be using both) then you're screwed, sorry. Learn how to use both and start using them from now on.

Comment: Here are links how to get started with the two things I mentioned above: http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht1427 and http://www.appcoda.com/git-source-control-in-xcode/ you need both of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, Xcode is quite good about this. When you delete a file, it asks whether you really mean this - you must have told it that you did - and if you do, it either deletes only the reference (leaving the file in the project folder) or moves the file to the trash. So the file still exists, in one of those places.

Comment: ah great point! I didn't think of that (I always delete files with `rm`). But still, git and time machine (or something equivalent) should be in place for every Xcode project.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Every Xcode project and everything else you do!